# Azure Worker Role / Web Role not reading from ServiceConfig

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles, azure-configuration

I have an Azure Worker Role (WR) which is *supposed* to pick up it's config from the .cscfg files using:

```
var setting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("My.Setting.Name");
```

Running in the emulator this is fine, I get the:

```
Getting "My.Setting.Name" from ServiceRuntime: PASS.
```

message. However, when I publish to my remote environment, I get:

```
Getting "My.Setting.Name" from ServiceRuntime: FAIL.
Getting "My.Setting.Name" from ConfigurationManager: FAIL.
```

messages. In the 'CloudServices/Configure' section of the Azure Management Portal I can see the setting listed in the configuration, and it's set correctly.

I'm using Azure SDK 2.0

Comment: How do you get `Getting "My.Setting.Name" from ServiceRuntime: PASS.` messages?

Comment: Locally - Using the Console Emulator UI, Cloud - using diagnostics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you deploying correct Azure SDK .DLL's with your project?  Did you by chance upgrade recently to a newer Azure SDK?  I would check your .DLL references to make sure that they all match across the solution

Comment: It *is* this problem, but due to me using the Nuget Packages for Azure config etc (which is 1.8) and the SDK which is 2.0

Comment: Holy codesticles!!! My code was using nuget 1.8.0.0 also ... instead of the 2.0's This answer saved my life. I'm back baby!! i'm back!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, I had the same issue with a WebRole not reading the Cloud config settings and going straight to the web.config file.